# jsPDF: issue with two-page pdf within Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: jspdf

I am facing the issue with two-page pdf within Adobe Acrobat Reader.
I am creating 2 page pdf using jsPDF doc.fromHTML() method.

My pdf is shown properly with header and footer when opened with any browser. Al, so my printer is printing it properly

When I am opening it in adobe reader the second page is showing error while printing the pdf and even footer is also not present on the second page.

Please, can anyone help me in solving this issue?

I tried doc.addPage() but it's adding a blank page

Error Message while printing with Acrobat:
An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try doc.addpage then add text to the second page using doc.text or doc.html

Comment: My content is dynamic and coming from back end java code. Some time it's one page and some time it grows to 3 page also.

Comment: fromHtml is already taking care of adding page. If I am adding one more page with doc.addpage() then one blank page is getting added. Error is still seen.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for days to fix that issue and found that it was causing from

```
setLineDashPattern
```

function.

I used dash patterns multiple times in my document and whenever I need to remove this global "line dash" settings from the document I was calling

```
doc.setLineDashPattern([0], 0);
```

When I debug my code line by line I found that this was the part that causes Adobe Acrobat to raise an exception. So I changed it to

```
doc.setLineDashPattern([], 0);
```

And viola!

Hope it helps someone, since I couldn't find anything about that.

Cheers